# Matlab how to overcome nchoosek limitation which only allow up to 15

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, combinations

I have some problem in using `nchoosek` because this function is only practical for situations where `v` is less than about 15.

```
C = nchoosek(v, k);
```

Below is a line of code where I want to include more v but it returned me "Out of memory" error in matlab. This line of code give me different combination of items, it starts with combination of 3 items.

```
A = [2 1 3];   
B = [4 2 1 3 3];
C = [1 3];
D = [3 2 4 2 1 1];
E = [4 1 1];
F = [...];
G = [...];
etc.

combs = arrayfun(@(x) nchoosek({A,B,C,D,E,...},x), 3:numel({A,B,C,D,E,...}), 'Uniform', 0);
```

I have `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, ... up to 8000++ of them.

What other methods can I use to solve this issue? as well as prevent run out of memory issue. Thanks.

Comment: I think that the out of memory issue is not something you will solve. Matlab itself tells that `nchoosek` shouldnt be used with `length(v)>5`.

Comment: Why do you need all those combinations in the first place? Start by considering (or reconsidering) that.

Comment: Maybe you should think again how to formulate/solve your problem. nchoosek(1000,3) ~ 1.66*10e8, nchoosek(1000,10) ~ 3*10e23, this is comparable to the estimated number of stars in the observable Universe! Hopefully you've got a powerful computer..

Comment: Assume that you have 12000 ( length(v)=13 ) possible combinations and the computation time for excluding or confirming a possibility is 0.01 second. It is hard to tell if this is realistic because I do not know what it is used for, but it does not really matter for this example. Anyway the total computation time for confirming or rejecting all combinations is then 100 seconds. This does not need to be unrealisic. However, increase `v` to length 21 (=>3.7e6 elements). This will increase computation time to 37000s (11 h). As you see including all combinations quickly becomes unrealistic.